# Adding markers to a Google map on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I've got a place I want to add on my map at a particular lat / lng. I'd like to display that on my map when the activity starts. How would I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[This Google/Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) should provide exactly the information you need.

Basically you create an custom [`ItemizedOverlay`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html), grab a list of overlays from the [`MapView`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html) ([`getOverlays`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#getOverlays())), create some [`GeoPoint`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html)s and your set.

The [Google Maps library documentation](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html) is a great reference for map related questions.